# when sql connection is opening session become empty. What is the relation of sql connection and session

Tags: asp.net, session, null, sqlconnection

I have a problem about session variables.
Session variables is deleting random time in my website. When i explore the problem i realize that session is reseting at opening sql connection. Not at every connection open time but some of them. I am using .net entity framework.
Is there anybody tell me what is the relation sql connection and asp .net session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my code saving session parameters in database and my problem solved. So i couldn't understand what is the problem. It's maybe about session timeout.

Answer (score 0):

Increase the session timeout and then check::
http://forums.asp.net/t/1283350.aspx

Comment: I changed but this problem not about this. Because i already have logon validation. When session timeout expire, logon page is opening.
I explore the problem. And i realize that sometimes when sql server connection is opening session become null. 
Is there any relation about sql connection and session?

Comment: Are you using state server or sql server mode ?

Comment: InProc mode. I didnt change anything about this.
I dont see this problem in my local. When i upload to hosting server i see this problem. I tried different hosting server but problem not finished. 
Supposably this problem proceed from sql connection. But i dont understand why? I am using .net entity framework.